# Implications creating System Accounts "useradd -r" Linux Fedora/RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, group, administration, useradd

I want to know what are the implications of create an account using `-r` option?

`# useradd -r ...`

The help says:

```
-r, --system
  Create a system account.

  System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their 
  numeric identifiers are chosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in
  /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their GID counterparts for the
  creation of groups).

  Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless
  of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the
  -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.
```

But, beyond assign lower values to *uid*, *gid* and *groups*.

**Question 1**
What files are affected?

**Question 2**
What additional performance this type system account presents?

**Question 3**
What behavior ignores or stops submit?

**Question 4**
Can I change an account created with the "-r" option to an account as if it were created without that option?

Comment: Check this [post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/useradd-r-option-and-system-account-question-892978/)...

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the current [source for useradd](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-shadow/shadow.git/tree/src/useradd.c), one can see exactly what else changes when `-r` is specified:

- subordinate uid/gid feature is disabled
- mail directory is not created

So, no major difference from regular user account.  Certainly no automatic performance gain or loss.   I am not sure what you mean by Q1 and Q3; as for Q4 -- technically, yes; but since that involves changing user ID, any files owned by former UID must be `chown`ed to new one.

Answer (score 1):

It assigns UID/GID < 1000 vis:

```
$ sudo useradd -r  -U kismet
$ grep kismet /etc/passwd /etc/group
/etc/passwd:kismet:x:977:970::/home/kismet:/bin/bash
/etc/group:kismet:x:970:
```

Accounts with a UID<1000 are not normally listed by GDM (the login screen).